# Return csv response from Firebase Google Cloud endpoint

Tags: firebase, csv, google-cloud-functions

I've created an endpoint, meaning `functions.https.onRequest` for exporting events in csv format. I have a function `generateCSVEvents` to map events in case some of the values in database are empty.

The problem is that the downloaded csv file shows data in one line (shown in photo).

[image]

Here's my function with an example of events array:

```
exports.events = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   let csvEvents = generateCSVEvents(events)
   res.status(200).contentType('text/csv').send(csvEvents);
}

function generateCSVEvents(events: any[]){
  const csv = [
     ["id", "author", "club", "title"],
     ...events.map(item => [
        item.id, 
        item.author,
        item.club,
        item.title
     ])

]
}
```

What am I missing to export data in correct csv format so it's displayed in multiple rows?

Comment: If you try to print `csv`, what do you get?

Comment: [objects-to-csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objects-to-csv) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
res.status(200).contentType('text/csv').send(csvEvents);
```

for

```
res.attachment('NAME_OF_FILE.csv');
res.status(200).send(csvEvents);
```

and format 'csvEvents' as string with proper separator.